# Data not saved in Coredata SQLITE file, will only appear on database on next app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

When we are saving data on coredata, the data weren't inserted on the database (sqlite file) right away. Instead, you have to quit and relaunch the app for it to reflect.

Here's my test code:

```
//Create New Object
NSString *entityName = NSStringFromClass([Blog class]);
Blog *blog = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                                           inManagedObjectContext:[[ContextManager sharedInstance] mainContext]];

blog.dotComID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1111111];
blog.url = @"";
blog.visible = YES;

//Save
NSError *error = nil;
[[[ContextManager sharedInstance] mainContext] save:&error];
```

And on the here's the code for mainContext:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *const)mainContext
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        context.parentContext = self.writerContext;
        _mainContext = context;
    });

    return _mainContext;
}
```

On **First launch**, these lines were executed. However, when i checked the sqlite file, the data was not saved - sqlite still empty.

On **Second Launch** (quit the app), it will reflect on the SQLITE already.
Upon checking, the sqlite was reloaded after the execution of this line:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[ContextManager sharedInstance] mainContext];
```

> Note: There are no saving code / mechanisms in **applicationWillTerminate**

What could be causing this problem?

---

Help guys, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know how we would be expected to answer this given the information provided. You need to post some code, show how you've tried to diagnose the issue.

Comment: as Pierce said it is difficult to answer without the code but my guess is that you don't do something like `managedContext.save()` and since the managedContext is saved in `applicationWillTerminate` you get the core data saved only there. What do you mean `We are not executing any saving mechanism on`?  When you tick on core data in your project, Apple is nice to setup everything for you so you should have `        self.saveContext()` inside `applicationWillTerminate`

Comment: thanks pierce and mat, edited the question with more details :)

Comment: You need to propagate the changes to the persistentStoreCoordinator. The save in the mainContext, will push the data changes to its parent context. So, you need to call the save repeatedly and the final context which doesn't have any parent and is associated with the persistentStoreCoordinator will write the data to the disk.

Comment: How are you trying to find the entries after saving changes? What code, specifically, does your app use that finds no new data?